# SSH server on windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssh

What can I install as a free ssh server for Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Here on [this link](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/install-SSH-Server-Windows-Server-2008.html) you will find list of available SSH server for windows server 2008.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The only realistic option is OpenSSH, but it has problems with key-based authentication. FreeSSHD is terrible in regards to standards compliance. So we chose Bitvise SSH server - it has very moderate pricing for small groups.

Comment: I have been happy with Bitvise, as well.  Also, there SFTP server is very good.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). It's an attempt to emulate basic linux functions and shell on windows.

Comment: You *could*. But you shouldn't.

Comment: hmmm... a less invasive software?

Comment: Just that in some ways Windows isn't really designed to work from a shell for much. It kind of depends on what you're trying to do that you'd want a SSH server. In many cases it's better instead of grafting SSH on Windows to just run a *NIX type OS...depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Unless something has changed, I had noticed in the past that the cygwin SSHD port tended to eat the processor up. But again it may have been fixed.

Comment: I completely agree that it's not a great solution, but it's an option. I personally haven't used cygwin and a couple years. I had to give it up because after a couple if commands it would stop correctly displaying what I was typing.

Comment: OpenSSH for Windows is free. There's a good guide on this at: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Answer (score 0):

The best free solution which is also as minimalist as realistic is this:

http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/

You do get the bare minimum of baggage from cygwin that allows ssh to start up and run, other than that it runs as a native service.

Still - as what you can do over the command line is relatively limited on windows, you'll want to tunnel RDP or something similiar over the ssh connection.  Unless you are simply using it to transfer files.

Comment: Why would you tunnel RDP if RDP is already encrypted?

Comment: It limits the number of services you have listening on external interfaces.

Comment: Though the actual point was that with a minimalistic ssh setup, you only have access to the windows shell, which may not allow you to do everything you want to.